# Global variable losing it's value after Project is closed

Tags: vba, excel, ms-project

I have a collection as a global variable, that would have Project Task objects in them.

The structure of my macro would be the following:

```
Public TaskCollection As Collection
Sub Main()
   Set TaskCollection = New Collection

   GetData(List of project paths)

   For Each task in TaskCollection
        //ProcessTask()
   Next

End Sub


Function GetData(List of project paths)
    for each project path
         Open project p

            //do something else with the opened project...

            for each Task t in p.Tasks
                TaskCollection.Add t
            next
        Close project p
         //AFTER THIS, the TaskCollection object will be totally empty
   next
End Function
```

As i mentioned in the comments, after I close the project, from where I got the tasks into the TaskCollection, the TaskCollection loses it's values. The weird thing is, that it keeps the number of objects it had before, but they're all empty;

I tried to make a collection object locally in the GetData function, and then pass it in the TaskCollection global variable at the end, but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding references to objects when you add a `Task` to the `Collection`.  These **references only have meaning so long as the objects they refer to exist**.  Those objects are destroyed when the project is closed.

If you want to use their data, you will need to copy it using value types (`String`, `Integer`, etc.) and not refer to the objects.  Or, you can keep the project open until you are done using the objects.

Comment: Oh, that makes so much sense! Thanks Byron for the answer. Is there a way to copy the whole object reference into an object that will not die when the project closes?

Comment: You are wading into a mess.  That technique is called a `deep copy` where you take all the data and put it into a new object.  Not sure what VBA provides on that front.  You will do better to create your own class and move over only the data you want.  The problem becomes one of how to handle the references that exist inside the `Task`.  Do you copy all of those too?  What about their references?  If you know which properties you want, just grab those and store them somewhere.  It's unlikely you need _all_ of it.